# Why are some RichFaces artifacts not in Maven Central?

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces, repository

In order to get the RichFaces Validator artifact `org.richfaces.ui.validator:richfaces-ui-validator-ui` (4.2.2 Final) in my build, I had to add https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases as repository in my POM.

I went that way after my build complained it couldn't find that artifact and [a search for 'richfaces' in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Crichfaces) did not return the "complete set" of RichFaces artifacts.

Just curious if anyone knows how RichFaces artifacts are chosen for inclusion in Maven Central.

Comment: Try to post this on RichFaces forums, they could give you the support you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: if you need this, you're probably doing something wrong.  Maven Central should have all the dependencies required to create an app with RichFaces.

I was trying to add the ui-validator component separately (which is not deployed to Maven central) under the mistaken assumption that I needed it explicitly identified as a dependency.  Including it caused me a considerable amount of pain (multiple `csv.xml` files in deployment).

In the end, I realized that the ui-components dependency (which *is* installed on Maven Central) bundles up the validation dependency (and many others).

In the end, I wasn't getting the components I was looking for anyway.  I thought I needed the `rich:ajaxValidator`, but that was only because I was attempting to use code from the 3.x RichFaces Showcase in a 4.x app (and that tag was removed in 4.x).